# Group list items by their name

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, grouping

I have a list with duplicate items. I need to group them in the same order.

i found many solutions in LINQ to group list items based on some key.

For example:-

i have a list like below

```
tbl1
tbl1
tbl2
tbl3
tbl1
tbl4
tbl2
```

i need to group it like the below

```
tbl1
tbl1
tbl1 
tbl1
tbl2
tbl2
tbl3
tbl4
```

Can this be achieved.

Comment: Sounds more like ordering than grouping

Comment: Use the .OrderBy(u => u.GroupID), instead, this will give you what you seek :-)

Comment: i dont have any field like groupID. i hv only a list with items like how i hv shown in example

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a grouping, you want to change the order of the list. C# has this naturally built in using the `Sort()` method.

Based upon your question, I'm **ASSUMING** your `userList` is a `List<string>`. That being the case, just use the code:

```
userList.Sort();
```

Assuming, however, that your `userList` is a `List<SomeObject>` instead, you could do this using Linq in the following way:

Assuming your object was something like:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string Name;
    // Whatever other properties
}
```

you could use:

```
var userList = new List<MyObject>();
// Whatever extra code...
userList = userList.OrderBy(v => v.Name).ToList();
```

Hope that does the trick!

Comment: i dont want to sort it. it will change the order. i want to group them in same sequence

Answer (score 0):

You can use GroupBy() method directly.

```
List<string> elements = new List<string>() //lets consider them as strings
{
  "tbl1",
  "tbl1",
  "tbl2",
  "tbl3",
  "tbl1",
  "tbl4",
  "tbl2"
};
var groups = elements.OrderBy(x=>x).GroupBy(x => x);//group them according to their value
foreach(var group in groups)
{
  foreach (var el in group) Console.WriteLine(el);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to group them, but the example you give indicates that you need to order them.

If you want to remove duplicate items, you need:

```
var groupedCustomerList = userList
    .GroupBy(u => u.GroupID)
    .ToList();
```

But, if you need to order them as shown in the example you need to write something like this:

```
var groupedCustomerList = userList
    .OrderBy(u => u.GroupID)
    .ToList();
```

or

```
var groupedCustomerList = userList.Sort();
```

Comment: i am not using any groupid in my list. that was just for example.

Comment: @Aswini GroupId was just an example. You say you want to group them, but the example which you gave says you sort them. If you want an output just like your example, just use yourList.Sort()

Answer (score 0):

You can expand `Group`s with a help of `SelectMany`:

```
   var groupedCustomerList = userList
     .GroupBy(u => u.GroupID)     // Grouping
     .SelectMany(group => group)  // Expand groups back (flatten)
     .ToList();
```

What's going on:

```
initial:          {tbl1, tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl1, tbl4, tbl2}
after GroupBy:    {Key = "1", {tbl1, tbl1, tbl1}},
                  {Key = "2", {tbl2, tbl2}},
                  {Key = "3", {tbl3}},
                  {Key = "4", {tbl4}},
after SelectMany: {tbl1, tbl1, tbl1, tbl2, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4}
```

Comment: I am not using groupid in my list. i just have list of names which has to be grouped